# Identify when single page app is running as a nw.js app

Tags: javascript, ember-cli, node-webkit, nw.js

How can I identify if your single page web app is running with `nw.js` (previously known as `nodewebkit`) via javascript? I'd like to be able to share the code between the web client and the `nw.js` app, while being able to figure when to use different code based on the running implementation.

I'm not sure if determining this while the app is running, is the best approach, as I should probably have an entirely different build task for the tool, but this seems like the path of least resistance at the moment, as I'm unfamiliar with most of `ember-cli`'s features (my current build tool) along [with the following module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-node-webkit).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
window.IS_NW = typeof window.process !== 'undefined'
```

However this will be a false positive if there is already a defined global named `process`.